# Subset based on two lists and within values

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have two long lists (n=100,000) of x and y coordinates and I want to subset everything east of the boundaries (black dots). However, the boundaries are not uniform (think coastlines). How can I subset (remove) based on the x and y coordinates of the two lists and within the values?

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

dat = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 2.5], 'y': [12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 13, 10, 11.5, 13, 11]})
setx = [1, 1.5, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 1]
sety = [11, 11.5, 12, 13, 14, 14.5, 15]
```

In the picture below, I want to remove all blue dot observation outside of the black dots (boundaries). How can I accomplish this using conditional states where each element of `sety` and `setx` is compared to ensure it subsets east of the boundaries?

**Plot**

```
plt.scatter(dat['x'], dat['y'], alpha=0.5, data = dat)
plt.scatter(setx, sety, alpha=0.5, data = dat, color = 'black')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**edit**

Forgive my vagueness. I've tried to clean up the wording. The main question is how to remove all observations east of the black dot boundary? I'm not sure how to incorporate the pair-wise list.

Comment: Several things are unclear about your question. How did you plot the graph? What is meant by "I want to subset everything outside of the black dots."?

Comment: I'm unclear on what you want, due to lack of example.  You want things "outside" the black dots in one place, but "east" in another.  Your example shows blue dots on both sides.  Coastlines are not this simple; I'm not sure how far your metaphor applies.

Comment: Are the black dots the boundaries?

Comment: "Subset" is not a verb in general; it's used in rare cases to describe a language situation that doesn't apply here.

Comment: I agree, the question is too vague to figure out what you are truly need

Comment: If the question is simply "which of these points is directly to the right of a black point", I would expect to see your coding attempt already; that's a simple list search for "same row" and a trivial comparison on the x-coordinate for "to the right".  What *is* the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, what you can do is use the shapely library which provides a group of natural language [relationships](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#relationships) between geometric objects (contains, intersects etc...)

Here a possible approach:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

# Create the filtering area (a polygon)
poly = Polygon(zip(setx, sety))

# Create a column converting your coordinates in point objects
dat['point'] = dat.apply(lambda x: Point(x.x, x.y), axis=1).values

# Apply the above mentioned method to get the index of the points within the filtering polygon
indices_within_region = dat['point'].apply(lambda x: poly.intersects(x)).values

# Subset your df
dat[indices_within_region]

# Result
     x       y      point
0   1.0     12.0    POINT (1 12)
1   1.0     13.0    POINT (1 13)
2   1.0     14.0    POINT (1 14)
```